# Cannot use type guard with string to access object

Tags: typescript, react-typescript

I am a bit confused. I have this layout

```
export enum Gender {
    male = 1,
    female = 2,
    other = 3
}

export const GENDER_MAP: Record<Gender, string> = {
    [Gender.male]: "male",
    [Gender.female]: "female",
    [Gender.other]: "other"
}
```

```
export const GENDER_RADIO_BUTTONS: RadioButtonsProps[] = [
    {
        label: 'M',
        value: Gender.male,
    },
    {
        label: 'F',
        value: Gender.female,
    },
    {
        label: 'O',
        value: Gender.other
    }
]
```

I am also having a `<RadioButtonGroup />` which returns a `string` as a `value` in the `onChange()`

```
<RadioButtonGroup
   onChange={value => console.log(GENDER_MAP[value])}
    radioButtons={GENDER_RADIO_BUTTONS}
    ... />
```

Ultimately I am trying to access `GENDER_MAP[value]` in the `onChange()`. However, TypeScript complains that the `value: string` cannot be used to index `GENDER_MAP`. How would I tell TypeScript that it can use `value` to index `GENDER_MAP`?

I tried

```
GENDER_MAP[value as keyof typeof Gender]
```

But no luck.

Answer (score 0):

The `GENDER_MAP`'s keys are `Gender`, so you can use the `GENDER` enum to index the object.

if you want to achieve it with type-casting, you can use

```
GENDER_MAP[value as Gender]
```

but it's **better** to define that the callback `onChange` should only be called with `value: Gender`

```js
type RadioButtonGroupProps = {
    onChange: (value: Gender) => void
    // ....
}
```

this way you won't see any errors trying to use it as index

[TS Play](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=50&ssc=24&pln=53&pc=3#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wG4AocpAD0ljiQDsBXPAcSYBMko4BvcnCFwQKADZI4AXjgBGADSDhmJKInS4AJkXC4EGAAseGgMzkAvpRp14aCIwDO8NgFEAcgBEXCAPoBZAEEABQAuRCQ7KE4AHg5Gbih5OCcoYEYAcwA+DQFdAG04hIA6NSQAXTCAIlLKnWECrh4ilVKKuEqW8SRapSEG+Kb9Iyg2yqGeSosqWmhbeyc4V09vHwQAjwBJAHkfACEAVQAVQ623AGUwhBROYAhd5hgYeaCcMAc8so083v4f3TEUAAjJBiML4Pz4Oq6IQAN3EzCQYUKTVKULg5jRuWhQgBwNBBAAYpC-sI4WIEUjGlBmqoumiMT8sdjcSCwVtidjYfDEYsqUVxlAfpYypQYABPMCSK43O4PJ6OF4QN45H4s-EpNLpNFkim8gaJKbkcWSxDXW73R72Ng4ZhgRXKmRMvSMADCBhQGR5AAodTzkVAAJTSbIwiDATg-KBm2WWxyXaMW+UOe3vEWWch2RzwaXmuVWm1gDRep32N0e9JINFRmWJ+YWeM1vOMa0QW0poNSbJen7RG4wzIkoR8au52MOEooMBe4twX3ojtdwfQ6JpMAPODGpBSSojiCVOCMFAgLc76P70vuz1SPhepALhhFGAoKAVmBFNBGNAAayQnDgADJ-2dMtPR9bkA3MOAAHoB05OAAwgnsoL7AcA0oTMFhgJAnE1It7y9aIcxjeUW1tH4L3LLc+DnTs4AwiAJCKMQIHSL0li8XxAiCPJfTKRDdF3WtHGvdiVjWTYdgOY5TjOSwYIDIA)

Comment: This is not working `GENDER_MAP[value as Gender]`. I am getting: `Conversion of type 'string' to type 'Gender' may be a mistake because neither type sufficiently overlaps with the other. If this was intentional, convert the expression to 'unknown' first.`. When I change it to `GENDER_MAP(value as unknown as Gender)}` I get `This expression is not callable. Type 'Record<Gender, string>' has no call signatures.` I cannot change `onChange: (value: Gender) => void` because `<RadioButtonGroup />` is used with various values, not only gender. It needs to be dynamic.